# Incapsula Rate Limit Per Second

Tags: firewall, rate-limiting, web-application-firewall, incapsula

I'm looking at the rate limiting on Incapsula, which limits requests etc. based on per minute.

```
Rate >= {api-rate;4}
```

Is there a way to rate limit based on per second?
So if an ip exceeds 1 request per second, then block it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate is in sliding window of 1 minute calculated every second, therefore you ca use:
Rate >= {api-rate;60}

Comment: Hmm the only problem here is that the rule won't take effect immediately, but rather after 60 seconds. I was hoping for it to work after a few seconds.

Comment: This is not correct, as rate is calculated every second, once 60 requests passed (even in 1 second), it will trigger.

Comment: You can now create custom rate rules with a counter value between 10 and 300 seconds. https://docs.imperva.com/bundle/cloud-application-security/page/rules/rates.htm